# Infimum of $\frac{||u'||^p_{L^p}}{||u||^p_{L^p}}$ for $u \in W^{1,p}_0((0,1))$

Tags: optimization, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Good afternoon everyone!

It is very easy to show that the infimum mentioned in the title is strictly positive, but it seems much more difficult to show that it is attained within the Sobolev space of traceless functions.

I do not know what to do to show this, because the best we can do is to extract a minimizing weakly convergent sequence (for $p > 1$) $x_{k_n}$. This does not seem to help since the norm is not weakly continuous.

The only theorem I know for proving such results for weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous functions needs the set to be closed and convex, while the circumference is not.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is not closed and convex?

Comment: The problem is equivalent to have the infimum of the norm of the derivative attained on the unit circumference (functions with Sobolev norm equal to 1). This circumference is not convex and therefore not weakly closed (in fact, it's weak closure equals the whole unit ball).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found something. We want to show that the infimum of the norm of the derivative is attained on the intersection of our space with the unit circumference of $L^p$.

All we need is the Relich-Kondrachov theorem, which allows us to extract a weakly convergent minimizing sequence, which is strongly convergent in $L_p$. Therefore if $u$ is the limit, then $||u||_{L^p} = 1$ and $||u'||_{L^p} \leq m$, where $m$ is our infimum.

Moreover, trace is a continuous function with the weak topology of the Sobolev space (easy), therefore $u$ has also a zero trace. Now  $||u'||_{L^p} \geq m$, therefore the two inequalities give $||u'||_{L^p} = m$ with $||u||_{L^p} = 1$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right. But let me tell you what you are actually doing here. This is actually an minimizing problem in calculous of variation. (of course I believe you are already very well realized about this)

Let me re-write you problem in a more standard way in calculus of variation:

Finding the minimizer of functional 
$$ E[u]:= \|u'\|_{L^p(0,1)}$$
among the admissible set 
$$ \mathcal A:=\{u\in W_0^{1,p}(0,1),\,\,\|u\|_{L^p(0,1)}=1\}$$

The first thing you need to prove is $\mathcal A$ is weakly closed w.r.t $W_0^{1,p}$. Yes, it is true, and this conclusion comes from the fact that $W_0^{1,p}(0,1)$ is weakly closed together Relich compactness theorem.

But here I have two questions for you.

a): why $W_0^{1,p}$ is weakly closed? This is not trivial, you need something from functional analysis, actually the Hanh-Banach theorem, to prove this. You said "*trace is a continuous function with the weak topology of the Sobolev space (easy)*" is "wrong", because from trace estimation, you only have trace is continuous w.r.t "strong" convergence in $W^{1,p}$ norm.

b): Why could you apply Relich? You are actually using a property called "coercivity" of $E$ defined above. Please check it and make sure you understand.

Of course, your idea is right, extract subsequence which is converge to a function $u$, but why this $u$ is the minimizer? That is, why $\|u'\|_{L^p}\leq m$? This is the fact that $L^p$ norm is "*weak lower semi-continuous*" w.r.t weak convergence in $L^p$. Please make sure you know what I am talking about.

In the end, let me point out this whole progress is called *direct method* in calculus of variation.

Lastly, the minimum value you found, is actually the **best** constant $C$ of Poincare inequality which states that there exists $C>0$ such that
$$ \|u\|_{L^p(0,1)}\leq C\|u'\|_{L^p(0,1)} $$
for all $u\in W^{1,p}_0(0,1)$

Comment: Well, for a), if we take any $f$ in the dual of the Lebesgue space of the boundary (the image of the trace), then $f(tr(u_n)) \rightarrow f(tr(u))$ by the weak convergence of $u_n$. This gives $f(tr(u)) = 0$. Therefore $tr(u) = 0$ because otherwise we would be able to find a bounded $f$ (By Hahn-Banach as you said), for which $f(tr(u)) \neq 0$.

Comment: hmm... no. Why you have $tr(u_n)$ weakly to $tr(u)$? The standard way to show $W_0^{1,p}$ is weakly closed is observing that $W_0^{1,p}$ is convex and strongly closed, and hence it is weakly closed. A set is CONVEX and strongly closed implies it is also weekly closed. This is the directly application of Hahn-Banach theorem

Comment: You are right for the continuity in a), since the preimages of open sets through the trace are open, but they have not to be weakly open. For b), The sequence is obviously bounded with the Sobolev norm, therefore we can extract a convergent subsequence with the $L^p$ norm. From this sequence, we can extract a weakly convergent subsequence wrt the Sobolev norm. Then it is easy to show that the two limits coincide.

Comment: No, what we have is that $f(tr(.))$ is a bounded functional and we use the weak convergence of $u_n$.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is a very good exercise in CoV. Nice job!

Comment: I never see any argument which consider about $f(tr)$ since the regularity of trace is not good, and actually the dual space is un-known.